# SOLR 7.5 java.lang.StackOverflowError when indexing pdf

Tags: solr

I have a fresh install of SOLR 7.5 in Ubuntu.  I've enabled enableRemoteStreaming and I'm attempting to index a pdf document and getting the error message "java.lang.StackOverflowError" back.

Here is a [link](http://www.jsoneditor.com/238p74r83ih) to the schema (in json as returned from a curl request). The pdf is not large and the heap has been increased to 4GB. A second attempt to index results in a HTTP 500 error "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider" and I have to restart SOLR.

It's acting like there is recursion happening that exhausts heap, but I don't understand why the default SOLR schema would produce that result.  Any help is appreciated.

Trace:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.sendError(HttpSolrCall.java:662)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:530)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:377)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)\nCaused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError\n\tat java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:406)\n\tat org.apache.fontbox.ttf.BufferedRandomAccessFile.fillBuffer(BufferedRandomAccessFile.java:122)\n\tat org.apache.fontbox.ttf.BufferedRandomAccessFile.read(BufferedRandomAccessFile.java:160)\n\tat org.apache.fontbox.ttf.BufferedRandomAccessFile.read(BufferedRandomAccessFile.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.fontbox.ttf.BufferedRandomAccessFile.read(BufferedRandomAccessFile.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.fontbox.ttf.BufferedRandomAccessFile.read(BufferedRandomAccessFile.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.fontbox.ttf.BufferedRandomAccessFile.read(BufferedRandomAccessFile.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.fontbox.ttf.BufferedRandomAccessFile.read(BufferedRandomAccessFile.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.fontbox.ttf.BufferedRandomAccessFile.read(BufferedRandomAccessFile.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.fontbox.ttf.BufferedRandomAccessFile.read(BufferedRandomAccessFile.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.fontbox.ttf.BufferedRandomAccessFile.read(BufferedRandomAccessFile.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.fontbox.ttf.BufferedRandomAccessFile.read(BufferedRandomAccessFile.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.fontbox.ttf.BufferedRandomAccessFile.read(

This last line keeps repeating until the output breaks

Comment: Please include the complete stacktrace for the error message - this might be a pdfbox/tika issue and not a schema issue.

Comment: Post edited to include the trace

Comment: That seems to be a borked font (ttf) parser issue when Tika is trying to parse the PDF file. Since the second error complains about the class failing to load - could it be a borked TTF file installed on the server? (I'm not familiar with how fontbox does it startup, but it seems to be font related - either embedded in the pdf or a system font)